# Update Panel and Content type issue in ASP.net page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a Update Panel and other controls in my ASPX page. 
After user selects few parameters and hit the submit button I am updating the database and I have a byteArray which gets populated.

When I run the application though the bytearray is getting populated, as the contentType is getting changed, it is throwing an error. Could you please let me know what I need to change to make it work.

```
byte[] doc=null;

doc=getByteArrayOfDocument(123);
if (doc != null)
                        {
                            Response.Clear();
                            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                            Response.Charset = "";
                            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=doc.pdf");
                            Response.AddHeader("content-length", doc.Length.ToString());
                            Response.AddHeader("content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
                            Response.BinaryWrite(doc);
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to modify the `Response`, you need a PostBack not an AsyncPostBack. So either put an `PostBackTrigger` on the `UpdatePanel` for the document view/download event, either put the action outside the `UpdatePanel`.